# android EventBus as LocalBroadcastManager replacement

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

greenrobot EventBus has been suggested as replacement of (now deprecated) LocalBroadcastManager. I'm current using LocalBroadcastManager to send intents from service to MainActivity like this:

```
val intent = Intent("service event")
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
intent.putExtra("param", "some value")
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

That clears the stack and MainActivity becomes visible as the only activity in the stack.

How can I achieve the same (`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`) effect when posting EventBus event?

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments, I found a "solution":

1. Register EventBus in `onCreate()` of MainActivity `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)`.  That makes it possible for MainActivity to receive posts even when it is not on top of the activity stack. Then, of course, unregister in `onDestroy()`.
2. In MainActivity event receiver function, start MainActivity again with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags, for example like this:

```
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
    fun onEventReceived(event: BusEvent) {
        val i = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        i.putExtra("action", event.action)
        i.putExtra("params", event.params)
        startActivity(i)
    }
```

I'm new to this and better solutions are appreciated.